# set default value for a textarea of rails fckeditor plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, fckeditor

I have a textarea in my view page and I am using rails fckeditor plugin for converting it into WYSIWYG editor. I need to set the default value for the textarea. How it is possible.I have written like this.. Please help

```
<%= fckeditor_textarea :reminder, :body,:lang => I18n.locale,:langdir => (rtl? ? 'rtl' : 'ltr') %>
```

Comment: Tried using the `value` attribute?

Comment: Yes.. I tried like this also...<%= fckeditor_textarea :reminder, :body,:lang => I18n.locale,:langdir => (rtl? ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'),:value=> "Hello.." %>... But it is coming as blank..

Comment: What is this plugin? Read the docs to see the arguments of `fckeditor_textarea`? Why not use this? https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor  And if you are using it inside a form builder block, shouldnt it be f.fckeditor... or something?

Comment: Its specific to my client. They need fckeditor rails plugin only.. So I installed this rails plugin in my application

Comment: PLease post links to whatever plugin you are using. Its impossible to identify your issue without it.

Comment: I have installed the plugin using the below link      https://github.com/gramos/easy-fckeditor

Comment: Are you sure `@reminder.body != ""` ?

Comment: Thanks it worked.. Infact @reminder was not the instance variable defined in controller.. it was new_reminder.. Thanks..

Comment: Okay okay. Good luck.